# Audio element play promise rejection even while audio context is in running state

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I am attaching a screenshot for reference to get more elaborated idea about the problem am facing.. Kind of hell.

I am well aware about autoplay policy and have gone through possible approches which involves user interaction. Also, am not a fond of displaying any screen or button to user to make him click, never, i do not want that.

I am developing a wordpress plugin and having microphone feature which can attach to textbpx on any wordpress website, user clicks on it (user interaction) comes in.

I have also read that i need to resume suspended audio context, which am doing and as you can see in screenshot the state of audio context "running" before and after audio elements play mathod.

I am using audio element created using Audio() constructor.

> **Note**: screenshot is a photo of mac system, I am debugging iphone xr using usb cable.

Can somebody help me out or enlighten me on what am doing wrong or there is any technical limitation.
[image: Error console screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh! after a week lasted hell finally I managed to make things works.

To give an overview of solution let me first describe high level rough idea of work flow which has problem on iOS Sfari.

**Problematic workflow**

> clickHandler --> AudioContext creation --> Playing audio using audio element.

All the audios followed by this workflow miserably failed in 'play' promise.

**Solution which worked for me**

> clickHandler --> **Play audio using audio element** -> AudioContext creation --> Playing audio using audio element.

The point of interest in a solution which worked for me is you have to play audio using audio element as first line of code in 'clickHandler'. No doubt the promise still fails but subsequent audios does play.

Also, I was creating new audio element for each new audio source to be played, Which was wrong as auto-play policy imposed on **'per-element'** basis. So instead of creating new audio element for each source I just create it once on page load (or whatever suits for you as one time creation) and whenever I want to play different audio file I just change the '.src' property/attribute.

So this is how It worked for me. I must mention throughout the week lasted hell, previously answered questions here and their problem specific solutions have been guiding light which gave me new perspective in a hunt for solution. Also the articles on internet, webkit , chrome, apple's documentation on Auto play policy helped a lot.